# JUnit Testing FacesContext.getExternalContext

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the following code in a Java EE managed bean:

```
FacesContext context = facesContextProvider.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext();
```

Where facesContextProvider is a custom class for returning the faces context (useful for mock testing).

I'm wondering how to test this in JUnit using mockito.  I am trying a combination of:

```
FacesContextProvider mockFacesContextProvider = mock(FacesContextProvider.class);
when(mockFacesContextProvider.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(mockFacesContext);
// this line is wrong ~> when(mockFacesContext.getExternalContext()).thenReturn((ExternalContext) new MockHttpServletResponse());
```

How can I inject some sort of mock or custom HttpServletResponse into my external context?

Thanks for the help.

**ANSWER**

My controller code is wrong.  You can work with the ExternalContext to do whatever you need.  So in the controller, it should actually be:

```
FacesContext facesContext = facesContextProvider.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
externalContext.responseReset();
```

If you still wanted the response, you could get it from:

```
HttpResponse response = externalContext.getResponse();
```

Then the unit test harness would be:

```
mockFacesContextProvider = mock(FacesContextProvider.class);
mockFacesContext = mock(FacesContext.class);
mockExternalContext = mock(ExternalContext.class);
mockHttpSession = mock(HttpSession.class);
when(mockFacesContextProvider.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(mockFacesContext);
when(mockFacesContext.getExternalContext()).thenReturn(mockExternalContext);
when(mockExternalContext.getSession(true)).thenReturn(mockHttpSession);
```

And then the Unit Test code would be:

```
verify(mockExternalContext).responseReset();
```

Comment: I can't mock ExternalContext.class because it's abstract... How did you make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FacesContextProvider mockFacesContextProvider = mock(FacesContextProvider.class);
HttpServletResponse mockResponse = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
when(mockFacesContextProvider.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(mockFacesContext);
when(mockFacesContext.getExternalContext()).thenReturn(mockResponse);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  i tried this unsuccessfully as well.  it would actually be HttpServletResponse mockResponse = mock(HttpServletResponse.class); when(mockFacesContext.getExternalContext()).thenReturn((ExternalContext) mockResponse);, however, this throws a class cast exception

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Is `ExternalContext` a subclass of `HttpServletResponse`?  If so, I don't think you need the cast in the original code; also you would need to mock `ExternalContext`, instead of `HttpServletResponse`.

Comment: yea, that's it. i'll update the original question and award you the answer since you got it here.